# How to accept user input in long, int or Guid and store it in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a Rest API in ASP.NET. The user could post a variable named ID that has a data-type of int, long or Guid.

How can I accomplish that knowing that I need to store this ID in the database?

Comment: How does the light turn on when you press the switch for it? Well, the interface was designed to work like that and only like that. The user has to follow the rules given by the interface. You define the API, you define the rules which will turn Knowing into Expecting

Comment: Do you have to know if the input was `int` or `long` (because `int` fits into `long`, so you *could* store them both as `long`)? You could have a table with (nullable) columns for each type you need (`long`, `Guid` and maybe `int`) and then another column with the "IDType", which tells you which column actually has the data. -- but storing is just one part. The (arguably) more important part is: how are you planning on using the IDs after you stored them? Are they foreign keys to other tables?

Comment: @sirRufo I am following a given specification. I am not writing the rules myself.

Comment: @Corak Yes, IDs are foreign keys to other tables. I agree with you I can store int as long but what about the Guid. I appreciate the idea of having an IDType column. I will try it and see.